# An Integer-Object: Does it become assigned by value or by reference to a method?

Tags: java, android

Following example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button doSmth;
    private Integer myInt = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        doSmth = findViewById(R.id.doSmth);
        doSmth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Counter counter = new Counter(myInt);
                counter.incrementCounter();
                Log.i("Final Counter", myInt.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The according Counter-class:

```
public class Counter {
    Integer counter;

    public Counter(Integer counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void incrementCounter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            counter = i;
            Log.i("Current Counter", counter.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The console-output when the onclicklistener becomes triggered:

```
... integerexample I/Current Counter: 0
... integerexample I/Current Counter: 1
... integerexample I/Current Counter: 2
... integerexample I/Final Counter: 0
```

I would have expected that Final Counter is 2. Because myInt is **an Integer-object** and object are passed by reference.

But obviously a copy has become passed because myInt is still 0.

**Can someone explain me the above described behaviour?**

Are objects of primitives wrapper-classes somehow handled differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Counter` constructor indeed a reference to the original `Integer` object is passed and stored.

However, the assignment `counter = i;` creates a new `Integer` object and assigns a reference to the new object to the variable `counter`. Thus the `myInt` still refers to the original object.

And by the way, `Integer` is immutable, meaning the value of an `Integer` object can never change. So even if you hold a reference it will always have the same value.

Comment: Ah, okay. As soon as I modify myInt, Java creates implicit a new one and then becomes the value of i assigned to that new Integer?

Comment: yes, this is called autoboxing. It happens when a primitive int is used in a place where an `Integer` is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just passed the value of `myInt` through the constructor and assigned that value to the new Integer `counter` which has nothing to do with `myInt`.

That's why `myInt`'s value is still 0.

I think you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/9782767) to have a better understanding regarding this matter.